# Quadratic Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

so i'm trying to find the general formula of a sequence, $${18,30,46,66,90,118}$$

i found the first difference, $${12,16,20,24,24}$$

second difference, $${4,4,4,4}$$

If the second difference is 4, you start with $2n^2$

Then i have $${18,30,46,66,90,118}$$

-$${2,8,18,32,50,72}$$

The residue is $${16,22,28,34,40,46}$$

which its formula is $16+6(n-1)$

So the final answer is $2n^2+16+6(n-1)$ which is $2n^2+6n+10$?

Does my approach seem on the right track?

Comment: Your formula does generate the numbers in your sequence. Why should you not be on the wrong track?

Comment: @Arthur thanks for the endorsement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *know* that the pattern is a quadratic, then you can use the method of finite differences. Otherwise, there are an infinity of formulas/patterns that will give you those six numbers in order.

---

Anyway, Let your quadratic be $$Q(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$$ with coefficients $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. We know

$$Q(0) = 18$$

$$Q(1) = 30$$

$$Q(2) = 46$$

As it turns out, three is enough to find everything we need to. The first equation above means that $$c=18$$

The second gives us $$a+b+c = 30 $$
or $$ a+b = 12$$

The third yields $$4a + 2b + 18 = 46$$

or

$$2a + b = 14$$

Since $a+b=12$, we get $$a=2$$

and $$b=10$$

---

Thus, $$Q(x) = 2x^2 + 10x + 18$$

As a check, you can find $Q(3)$, $Q(4)$, and $Q(5)$ to make sure they're $66$, $90$, and $118$, respectively.

Comment: thank you! I think this is another good method.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I teach my students to try it.  If the sequence's differences are constant, it's a linear progression.  If the sequence's differences' differences are constant, start with $cn^2$ and work from there.